# Position of player is incorrectly calculated

Tags: java, libgdx

In my player class the position vector of the player is consistently adding to the velocity vector of the class. I have an oldPosition Vector as well to see if the player has moved. I am using a 2d boolean array for collision throughout my game.

Here is the Player class.

```
public Player(){
    this.velocity = new Vector2();
    this.position = new Vector2(MapGrid.MAP_WIDTH / 2, MapGrid.MAP_HEIGHT + 200);
    this.oldPosition = position;
    this.gridPosition = new Vector2((int)(this.position.x / MapGrid.CELL_SIZE), (int)(this.position.y / MapGrid.CELL_SIZE));
}

public void create(){
    this.canFall = true;
}

public void update(){
    velocity.x += MainScreen.GRAVITY.x;

    System.out.println("Grid calc x- " + (int)(this.position.x / MapGrid.CELL_SIZE));
    System.out.println("Grid calc y- " + (int)(this.position.y / MapGrid.CELL_SIZE));
    System.out.println("position top x- " + this.position.x);
    System.out.println("position  top y- " + this.position.y);
    this.gridPosition.x = (int)(this.position.x / MapGrid.CELL_SIZE);
    this.gridPosition.y = (int)(this.position.y / MapGrid.CELL_SIZE);

    oldPosition.x = getGridPosition().x;
    oldPosition.y = getGridPosition().y;

    position.x += velocity.x;
    position.y += velocity.y;

    if(oldPosition.x == getGridPosition().x || oldPosition.y == getGridPosition().y){
        hasMoved = false;
    }
    else{
        hasMoved = true;
    }

    if(!canFall){
        velocity.y = 0;
    }else
        velocity.y += MainScreen.GRAVITY.y;

    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.A)){
        velocity.x -= 10 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    }
    else if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.D)){
        velocity.x += 10 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    }else
        velocity.x = 0;

    System.out.println("position after input x- " + this.position.x);
    System.out.println("position after input y- " + this.position.y);
}
```

and here is the MapGrid class. 
CELL_SIZE = 50

```
public void create(){
    for(int x = 0; x < mapGrid.length; x++){
        for(int y = 0; y < mapGrid[x].length; y++){
            mapGrid[x][y] = false;
        }
    }
}

public void addToMap(Collidables object){
    objectList.add(object);
}

public void update(){
    for(int l = 0; l < objectList.size(); l++){
        mapGrid[(int) objectList.get(l).getGridPosition().x][(int) objectList.get(l).getGridPosition().y] = true;
        if(objectList.get(l).hasMoved()){
            mapGrid[(int) objectList.get(l).getOldGridPosition().x][(int) objectList.get(l).getOldGridPosition().y] = false;
        }

        if(!objectList.get(l).isAlive()){
            mapGrid[(int) objectList.get(l).getGridPosition().x][(int) objectList.get(l).getGridPosition().y] = false;
            objectList.get(l).destroy();
        }
    }
}
```

and lastly the collision handler class

```
private Entity entity;
private MapGrid mapGrid;

public CollisionHandler(MapGrid mapGrid, Entity entity){
    this.entity = entity;
    this.mapGrid = mapGrid;
}

public void update(){
}

@Override
public void run() {
    if(mapGrid.getGrid()[(int) (entity.getGridPosition().x + 1)][(int) entity.getGridPosition().y]){
        entity.setCanMoveRight(false);
    }else
        entity.setCanMoveRight(true);

    System.out.println("X: " + (int) (entity.getGridPosition().x - 1));
    System.out.println("Y: " + (int) (entity.getGridPosition().y));
    /*=============================*/
    /*ONE LINE UNDER IS WHERE THE  */
    /*=========ERROR LIES!=========*/
    /*=============================*/
    if(mapGrid.getGrid()[(int) (entity.getGridPosition().x - 1)][(int) entity.getGridPosition().y]){
        entity.setCanMoveLeft(false);
    }else
        entity.setCanMoveLeft(true);



    if(mapGrid.getGrid()[(int) (entity.getGridPosition().x)][(int) entity.getGridPosition().y - 1]){
        entity.setCanFall(false);
    }else
        entity.setCanFall(true);
}
```

When I run the game the game shows for a couple seconds and then crashes with the following error report.
[image: Error]

The first two lines(grid calc) calculate where the player is in the grid, which is the players position / the cell size of the grid.
The second two lines(position top) of the console is the players position on screen.
The third two lines (position after input) is the same log as the normal position but I printed it at the bottom of the update method after the input.
And lastly the fourth 2 lines are printed from the collision handlers run method where the error lies.

I can't seem to find why the players grid coordinates are seemingly being divided constantly when in fact that is not happening. The grid coordinates are based on the players position divided by the cell size(50) and yet the players grid coordinates are being sent to -1 which is of course what is causing the error. I have looked everywhere and really need help here.

Comment: Hey, is your gravity set in the x dimension?

Comment: @warren it doesn't need it but it is, it is adding 0 constantly until you try to move

Comment: Well, the IndexOutOfBounds is easy to point out.  Because of the inherent error, the search for left ends up being 0-1 because (int)(20/50) is 0.  But, if the player was actually over on the left edge of the screen, you'd still be getting that error, so you'll have to make a check to see if that calculation is going to be 0 or not so that it will automatically return false for the left direction.

Comment: As for the other issue, which, incidentally, is almost completely unrelated, I can't help feeling like there is some code missing from your example, because getGridPosition() doesn't exist for Player as it stands.  Probably won't be able to fix it without seeing more, and I couldn't even tell you what I needed to see at this point.

Comment: I agree. with my hypothesis shot down, I am left to conclude that the error is probably not in the supplied code. Also, I thought the error in the first line would be fixed by now (position adding to velocity?)

Comment: @warren Why would that be a problem? The position is constantly being added to the velocity. If you move right the velocity += 3 so the position would move 3 to the right. I don't understand the problem please elaborate.

Comment: The velocity is being added to the position.

Comment: @warren yes it is, what seems to be the problem?

Comment: I also don't see the relevance.  I don't think anything's wrong with velocity being added to the position, as gridPosition is calculated off of position anyway.

Comment: ugh... (a+=b) != (b+=a)

Comment: i know that, position adds velocity and the position is getting updated the velocity is almost never equal to the player position @warren

Comment: How did I fail to explain this so badly? The error is in the order of the position and velocity vectors in that sentence. One implies that the result of the addition updates the velocity, which is clearly incorrect. One implies that the addition updates the position, which is necessarily true by the relationship of position and velocity. There is an alternate interpretation of a sentence containing the word 'to', but it does not make sense in context: An error that results in the wrong value stored needs to be analyzed in terms of assignments, not accesses.